# Add a slow fadein effect to my popup modal

Tags: jquery, events, fadein

Can someone show me how to do a slow fadein effect to my current popup modal which opens up on click event?

here is my code

```
var THRESHOLD = 5 * 1000;
var lastActive = Date.now();
$(window).on('click', function() {
    if (Date.now() > lastActive + THRESHOLD) {
     $('#modal').css('display','block');
    }
    lastActive = Date.now();
});
```

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default `fadeIn()`/`fadeOut()` function in jQuery you can use, there you can pass value in milliseconds which is speed of fading-in/out your content

```js
var THRESHOLD = 5 * 1000;
var lastActive = Date.now();
$(window).on('click', function() {
    if (Date.now() > lastActive + THRESHOLD) {
        $('#modal').fadeIn( 500 );
    }
    lastActive = Date.now();
});
```